# Pattern matching in compound if statements and switches with fall-through

Tags: c#, .net, pattern-matching

If I have an if statement like `if (currentShape is ITable table || currentShape is AutoShape autoShape)` I cannot use `table` or `autoShape` in the body because I get a [CS0165 compiler error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165).

The same is true for a switch statement with fall-through:

```
void Foo(object o)
{
    switch (o)
    {
        case int i:
        case string s:
        case Guid g:
            string bar = i?.ToString() ?? s?.ToString() ?? g.ToString(); // cannot use i, s, or g.
            break;
    }
}
```

I understand why, but I'm left wondering, is this a limitation of pattern matching, i.e. you cannot use it in compound `if` statements, or is there a correct way to construct the statement so I can use either variable (e.g. by initializing them to null so I can then at least do a null check)?

Comment: maybe this is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46255003/fall-through-in-pattern-matching. You can use discards if you don't like to make garbage local variables in current region. then you can use switched variable directly

Answer (score 6):

Since C# 9 you can do the followings

with switch statement

```
switch (o)
{
    case object probe when probe is int or string or Guid:
        string bar = probe.ToString();
        break;
}
```

and with switch expression

```
var bar = o switch
{
    int or string or Guid => o.ToString() 
};
```

Answer (score 5):

If truly there are two separate things to achieve, don't combine the pattern expressions.  Two separate if statements will work better.

```
if (currentShape is ITable table)
{
    // do something with tables
}

if (currentShape is AutoShape autoShape)
{
    // do something with autoshapes
}
```

However, your other example illustrates that perhaps there is some common functionality between the conditions.  `ToString()` is probably a bad example, as you could just do:

```
string? bar = o.ToString(); // doesn't matter the type of object
```

But let's say that perhaps you want a different format applied depending on the type.  In that case, a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) could be useful.  For example:

```
string? bar =
    o switch
    {
        int i => i.ToString("D3"), // three digits
        Guid g => g.ToString("N"), // no hyphens
        string s => s,    // no need to call ToString on a string
        _ => o.ToString() // all other types
    };
```

You also asked about whether the variables could be initialized with nulls so you could do a null check.  That wouldn't work for non-nullable types like `int`.  For nullable types, it would cause an extraneous compare operations (first to test the type and assign null, second to test for null).  Keeping the expressions separate ensures the minimal number of operations.